# PyTest: Остановка после провала одного конкретного теста

Tags: python, test-automation, pytest

Есть несколько тестов, все 15 тестов, зависят от первого (1ый тест: Авторизация на сайте), но ни как не связаны между собой.
Хочу реализовать следующее:
Если первый тест провалился (не авторизовались), то далее тесты пропускаются и не выполняются, если 1ый прошел, но провалился любой другой тест, то тестирование продолжает выполняться дальше.

Комманды:

```
pytest -x           # остановка после первого упавшего теста
pytest --maxfail=2  # остановка после первых двух упавших тестов
```

Не совсем подходят под логику реализации.

Comment: В документации вычитал про `SKIP` и `XFAIL`, но это снова не много не то, что необходимо

Comment: Вариант 1 - авторизацию сделать не тестом, а фикстурой с максимальным скоупом, от которой будут зависеть все тесты. Если она упадет с исключением, то ни один тест вообще не выполнится. Вариант 2 - Использовать плагин [pytest-dependency](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html), для всех тестов прописать зависимость от первого.

Comment: @insolor, благодарю, помогли мне.